# CSS DIV scrollbars min-width issue

Tags: jquery, background-image, jquery-cycle, css

I have a rotating image header (using jquery Cycle) that has a width of 1400px.
The site it sits within has a width of 960px.

When the browser is resized - I get horizontal scrollbars at 1400px.
I need them to ONLY start at 960px -  NOT 1400px.

Is this possible? I also need the header image to remain centered on resize.

You can view the site and the issue here....

```
http://108.174.144.176/~momandpo/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should force the container and the children to 100% width so it won't enlarge the layout. Since you use a centered background image, it will stay centered and be automatically cropped depending on the window width.

```
#bg_containers,
#bg_containers > div {
  width: 100% !important;
}
```

To avoid using !important, you can modify the script to not set a fixed width on these items.

Comment: That worked! I had 100% set on both divs but it failed. As soon as I added !important - it worked so thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 2):

Try to add this css:

```
#bg_containers div {
  width:100%;
}
```

You have there one container `#bg_container` and some child `div`'s.